# What's wrong with this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I am using the following javascript regex email validate function but it doen't seem to work why....

```
function IsValidEmail(email) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    return filter.test(email);
}

function forgetpassword() {
    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_TxtEmailId").value == "") {
        return false;// this condition gets exected so no prob with my txtboxID
    }
    if (document.getElementById("ctl00_TxtEmailId").value != "") {
        return IsValidEmail(document.getElementById("ctl00_TxtEmailId").value);
    }
    return true;
}
```

My failed inputs were `test,test@test and also test@test.com`

Guys my textbox is within a facebox modal popup.... when i tried `alert(document.getElementById("ctl00_TxtEmailId").value` with  some text `jsadf` the alert displayed with nothing... Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? False positive or false negative?

Comment: @KennyTM it doesn't return true for a valid email id

Comment: That "filter" is most likely wrong also.

Comment: If your house has a hole in the roof, do you call the maintenance guy and say "my house doesn't work"? How about being a bit more specific about how it fails to work exactly.

Comment: @Matti i ve editted my question...

Comment: have you checked to see if the DOM is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the regexp to something like

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

and I would rewrite forgetpassword to

```
function forgetpassword() {
    return IsValidEmail(document.getElementById("ctl00_TxtEmailId").value);
}
```

**Edit**: Complete function

```
function IsValidEmail(email) {
    var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
    return filter.test(email);
}
```

`IsValidEmail('janus@aaa.bbb') -> true` in Chrome / IE8

Comment: Have you checked the value of document.getElementById("ctl00_TxtEmailId").value? I don't have problems with this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Want to try this?

/^[a-zA-Z][\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9].[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.]*[a-zA-Z]$/